# How do I override error message on Left in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, pattern-matching

I want to read from file and am using pattern matching on Left/Right to tell is said file exists like so:

```
tehfile <- readIniFile "somefile_that_does_not_exist.ini"

s <- case tehfile of
    Left a -> print "woot"
    Right b -> ...
```

The error I'm getting is the one generated by Data.Ini library: "openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)".
Ideally, I'd like to override that text entirely or at least append my super useful "woot" string after the one produced by the library. How can I do that and why doesn't it happen in the code I have now?

Comment: Just return a `Left ""` then, so `Left a -> Left (a <> "woot")`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what this means in an answer? It seems to work but I have no idea what does this do...

Comment: also now I have `Couldn't match type ‘Either String’ with ‘IO’` error, because this code is in main::IO().

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [implementation for `readIniFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ini-0.4.1/docs/src/Data.Ini.html#readIniFile), it's just

```hs
readIniFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either String Ini)
readIniFile = fmap parseIni . T.readFile
```

First it tries to open and read the file, then it tries to parse the contents as an INI config. That first part would fail with an exception if the file doesn't exist, and the second fails with a `Left`. To print your own message and resume the computation, instead of pattern matching on the `Left` case you'll want to [`catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catch) the exception.

```
λ> import Control.Exception
λ> handler :: IOException -> IO (Either String Ini); handler _ = putStrLn "woot" >> pure (Left "woot")
λ> tehfile <- readIniFile "somefile_that_does_not_exist.ini" `catch` handler
woot
```

Or you can throw an error with your own message, to end the computation

```
λ> handler :: IOException -> IO (Either String Ini); handler _ = error "woot"
λ> tehfile <- readIniFile "somefile_that_does_not_exist.ini" `catch` handler
*** Exception: woot
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>...
```

Or write your own exception and throw that

```
λ> data Woot = Woot deriving (Show)
λ> instance Exception Woot
λ> handler :: IOException -> IO (Either String Ini); handler _ = throwIO Woot
λ> tehfile <- readIniFile "somefile_that_does_not_exist.ini" `catch` handler
*** Exception: Woot
```